# Writing a value to "data-" field from ASP.Net WebForm Code behind?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I would like to write a value from code behind to the "data-pagecount" field in a span tag on the page.
This is what I have so far in my html:

```
 <span id="searchResultPager" runat="server" data-pagecount="2">
```

I'm not sure how to write to the data-pagecount section of that tag in code behind. (easy in MVC but this is a legacy code base)

My intention is to then use this value from JQuery for a client side pager.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer was simplier then I thought.

```
searchResultPager.Attributes.Add("data-pagecount","123");
```